# Graphics Card for GA-970A-DS3P motherboard

Tags: graphics-cards, motherboard, desktop

### Problem

I have a **[Gigabyte GA-970A-DS3P](http://www.gigabyte.in/Motherboard/GA-970A-DS3P-rev-10#support-dl)** motherboard which doesn't have any inbuilt graphics so I paired it up with [**NVIDIA GeForce 210**](http://www.nvidia.in/object/product_geforce_210_in.html) Graphics Card. I am not satisfied with this graphics card as I am unable to do video editing and heavy gaming. So, I wish to buy a new GPU for the following tasks:

- Gaming: GTA V
- Video Editing: Camtasia, VLC
- Development: Android Studio (with emulator)

### Specification

- AMD FX 8350 Eight-core processor 4.00 GHz
- Gigabyte GA-970A-DS3P
- Ram 4.00 GB
- OS Windows 7 ultimate 64 bit

### Budget

- $100 - $150

Comment: It's usually the CPU that has integrated graphics, not the motherboard. In any case, you were never going to get GTA V performance out of a GTX 210 - it just about runs on an R9-280, which is roughly a GTX 780.

Comment: Along with the new GPU, I would highly advise increasing the amount of RAM in the system.

Answer (score 2):

Considering your budget and existing hardware, a Nvidia GTX 1050ti will fit your needs nicely.

My recommendation would be **Zotac's GTX 1050ti Mini**. However, you will get similar if not identical performance from other non-reference 1050ti(s).

You can find Zotac's 1050ti Mini for **$140 from [Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01MCU1ERO) or [Newegg](https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16814500411&cm_re=zotac_1050ti-_-14-500-411-_-Product).**

---

The GTX 1050ti fits your requirements:

- Within your budget.
- Compatible with your system.
- You can play GTA V and other games at reasonable quality.

Bonuses:

- CUDA support (GPU assisted rendering), if you use video editing software that's CUDA compatiable.
- Does not require PCIE power connectors. Its peak power consumption is <75W.

---

A couple things to take note of:

- You should not have bottlenecking issues with your FX8350.
- Your motherboard supports PCIe 2.0, but the GTX 1050ti is PCIe 3.0. This [wont' be an issue either](http://www.tomshardware.com/answers/id-3248140/gtx-1050-pcie.html).
- Make sure you have enough wattage headroom for additional components. Most builds do, but it never hurts to double check.

Comment: What about Zotac GeForce® GT 710 2GB?

Comment: @user3382203 [You can run GTA V with a GT 710](http://www.tomshardware.com/answers/id-2970004/zotac-710-2gb-graphics-card-good-card.html). However, you will be limited to lower quality, lower resolution or both to maintain non-slideshow frame rates. GTA V recommends at least a GTX 660, which significantly outperforms the GT 710.

Comment: @NZKshatriya Good point, I'll edit my response.

Comment: @0-60FPS  Welcome, gotta love that small fact that everyone takes for granted as common knowledge.